# Adding multiple instances of the same object

Tags: actionscript-3

Adding multiple instances of the same object
The movie clip disappears from the first object because the instance name is
Always the same is there a solution

```css
var mc1:Mc1=new Mc1();
var mc2:Mc2=new Mc2();


var ar:Array=new Array();

function fun(){
var i = 0;
while (i < ar.length) {
ar[i].width=864;
ar[i].height=651;
ar[i].x=200;
ar[i].y=200; 
ar[i].visible=false;  
addChild(ar[i]);
i++; 
}
TweenMax.staggerTo(ar,0, {visible:true},0.120);
}

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f1);
function f1(e:Event):void{
ar.push(mc1);//
}
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f2);
function f2(e:Event):void{
ar.push(mc2);
}
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f3);
function f3(e:Event):void{
ar.push(mc1);//
}
button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f4);
function f4(e:Event):void{
fun();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only ever creating two instances,  one of `Mc1` and one of `Mc2` at the very top of your code.  If you don't see the word `new`, your not creating any new instances.

What you likely are wanting to do, is store the Class in the array, then in the while loop create a new instance of that class.

1. Change the places where you push to the array, to push the class name, not the instances:

   ```
   ar.push(Mc1);  //instead of ar.push(mc1)
   ```
2. Remove those instances at the top

   ```
   //remove these two lines
   var mc1:Mc1=new Mc1();
   var mc2:Mc2=new Mc2();
   ```
3. Change your while loop to create a new instance of the class in the array

   ```
   var obj:MovieClip; //create a var to store your Mc objects in the loop below
   var i:int = 0;
   while (i < ar.length) {
       obj = new ar[i](); //this instantiates the class stored in the array at index i
       obj.width=864;
       obj.height=651;
       obj.x=200;
       obj.y=200;  
       obj.visible=false;      
       addChild(obj);
       i++;    
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Thank you